# Giving each Task a solution with the answers package

Tags: lists, answers, tasks

Currently I've this one as a starter MWE. It's messed up right at the start because it counts a `c)` at the beginning of the solutions but it is something to work with. How do I fix this?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{tasks}

\Opensolutionfile{mysolutions}
\Newassociation{mysolution}{mySoln}{mysolutions}

\begin{document}

\section{Questions}
\begin{tasks}(3)
\task $\int\sqrt{4-x}\mathrm{d}x$
\task $\int\sqrt{4-x}\mathrm{d}x$
\task $\int\sqrt{4-x}\mathrm{d}x$
\end{tasks}

\begin{mysolution}
\begin{tasks}(3)
\task $\int\sqrt{4-x}\mathrm{d}x$
\task $\int\sqrt{4-x}\mathrm{d}x$
\task $\int\sqrt{4-x}\mathrm{d}x$
\end{tasks}
\end{mysolution}

\Closesolutionfile{mysolutions}

\section{Answers!}
\input{mysolutions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In this case I matched every task environment with an answer but I want to **set an answer for each single task**.

Comment: Use `\,` before the differential.

Answer (score 4):

This label is generated by mySoln environment to suppress this use

```
\renewcommand{\mySolnlabel}[1]{\null}% suppresses the label
```

Full MWE is ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{tasks}

\Opensolutionfile{mysolutions}
\Newassociation{mysolution}{mySoln}{mysolutions}

\renewcommand{\mySolnlabel}[1]{\null}% suppresses the label



\begin{document}

\section{Questions}
\begin{tasks}(3)
\task $\int\sqrt{4-x}\mathrm{d}x$
\task $\int\sqrt{4-x}\mathrm{d}x$
\task $\int\sqrt{4-x}\mathrm{d}x$
\end{tasks}

\begin{mysolution}
\begin{tasks}(3)
\task $\int\sqrt{4-x}\mathrm{d}x$
\task $\int\sqrt{4-x}\mathrm{d}x$
\task $\int\sqrt{4-x}\mathrm{d}x$
\end{tasks}
\end{mysolution}

\Closesolutionfile{mysolutions}

\section{Answers!}
\input{mysolutions}
\end{document}
```